# Creative Commons ShareAlike (CC SA 1.0) is retired and not recommended for use, but there's not a suitable active alternative. Should I not use it?

Tags: license-recommendation, creative-commons

I have some graphic design creations that I want to allow others to modify if they wish to, as long as their remixed versions have the same permissions.

[Creative Commons ShareAlike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/sa/1.0/) (CC SA 1.0) exactly describes what I want, but that page has a notice that it is retired and not recommended for use.

There is an active license called [Attribution-ShareAlike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode) (CC BY-SA 4.0), however this requires that the modifier give credit back to me for the original. In the case of this project I don't want to require attribution as I feel it could be cumbersome and detrimental to future use by others (in other words, I care much more about the project's usefulness than I do about getting credit).

I could also release as [Public Domain](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/) (CC0), but I'm uncomfortable letting people make money off of my work.

The ["Reason for Deprecation" for CC SA](https://creativecommons.org/retiredlicenses) just says "Inadequate demand", which doesn't explain why I shouldn't use it now, but I don't understand if there's an actual practical reason why I shouldn't just do so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly advise against using any v1.0 Creative Commons license, since the most recent iteration is v4.0, and has made many improvements to clarity and enforceability (especially in varied international contexts). Furthermore, Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 (CC BY-SA) should suit you just fine.

CC BY-SA's attribution requirement in Section 3(a)(1)(A) requires recipients to

> retain the following **if it is supplied** by the Licensor with the Licensed Material:
>   identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material and any others designated to receive attribution...

So, if you don't supply any attribution information to be retained, this requirement doesn't have any effect.

Furthermore, Section 3(a)(3) says

> If requested by the Licensor, You must remove any of the information required by Section 3(a)(1)(A) to the extent reasonably practicable.

This is really intended to allow the removal of attribution for specific uses (e.g., use of your work in a political campaign you dislike), but I point this out to show that if *don't* wish to be attributed, CC BY-SA strongly respects this choice.